# nodemailer DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using this SMTP settings:

```
secure: true,
ignoreTLS : true,
port: 465,
```

But I am getting this error, and not able to sent email:

```
[Error: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT]
```

How can I ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work, just add this into `option.tls`:

```
{rejectUnauthorized: false}
```